# BigQuery load with Quoted new line

Tags: google-bigquery

I know we can use Quoted new lines option in BQ. But my data is not loading even with this option. I don't have any idea why its breaking the load.

CSV line:

```
"49602"|"AFFF7240654213"|"FROM MASTER: TESTing part. Goodluck: example.com/wp.png (tarifado) 
 
"|"MO"|||0.000|0.000|50.7000|"NET"
```

Its giving me this error.

```
Error while reading data, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 436388389. Error: Missing close double quote (") character.
```

But with with `allow-quoted-newline` it should work right?

Also here is the exact **column** from Postgres(the data source)

```
FROM MASTER: TESTing part. Goodluck: example.com/wp.png (tarifado) \r
\r
```

Comment: can you, please, provide information about the tool you are using for loading data? Is it BQ command-line tool? do you use bq load command?

Comment: I tried bq load cli and BQ console as well

Answer (score 1):

I stored your sample CSV line in a test.csv file and when running

```
bq load  --autodetect  --source_format=CSV dataset.test_table "gs://my-bucket/test.csv"
```

indeed I see the same error

```
Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 0. Error: Missing close
double quote (") character.
```

However when adding the flag for allowing quoted newlines it worked fine

```
bq load  --autodetect --allow_quoted_newlines --source_format=CSV dataset.test_table "gs://my-bucket/test.csv"
```

And the BQ table, test_table looks like this

| Row | int64_field_0 | string_field_1 | string_field_2 | string_field_3 | string_field_4 | string_field_5 | double_field_6 | double_field_7 | double_field_8 | string_field_9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 49602 | AFFF7240654213 | FROM MASTER: TESTing part. Goodluck: example.com/wp.png (tarifado) | MO | null | null | 0.0 | 0.0 | 50.7 | NET |